# problems scraping web page using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

Hi I'm quite new to python and my boss has asked me to scrape this data however it is not my strong point so i was wondering how i would go about this.

The text that I'm after also changes in the quote marks every few minutes so I'm also not sure how to locate that.

I am using beautiful soup at the moment and Lxml however if there are better alternatives I'm happy to try them

This is the inspected element of the webpage:

```
div class = "sometext"
<h3> somemoretext </h3>
<p>
<span class = "title" title="text i want">text i want</span>
<br>
</p>
```

I have tried using:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('the url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
r = soup.findAll('//span[@class="title"]/text()')
print r
```

Thank you in advance,any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention my output seems to be just [] as in no text however i would like to be getting the "text i want". cheers

Comment: Since you said the text changes evry few minutes, it is likely to be filled in by some JS script.  You might want to check you browser network inspector, since there is a possibility you will find a dedicated url for that text.

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho how would i go about finding the dedicate url and how to print that?

Comment: I would check your browser's developer tools, in particular the network inspector, and search the XXR requests for something that make sense.  It should be easy to spot, right before the text being updated.  If you can't find nothing there, then it's likely that all possible texts are stored either in some JS file or in a hidden DOM element.

Comment: If you can, add an example URL to your question, that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do this to get what you are looking at in the soup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup
```

That way you can double check that you are actually dealing will what you think you are dealing with.

Then do this:

```
r = soup.findAll('span', attrs={"class":"title"})
for span in r:
    print span.text
```

This will get all the `span` tags with a `class=title`, and then `text` will print out all the text in between the tags.

**Edited to Add**

Note that esecules' answer will get you the title *within* the tag (`<span class = "title" title="text i want">`) whereas mine will get the title from the text (`<span class = "title" >text i want</span>`)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps `find` is the method you really need since you're only ever looking for one element. [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

```
r = soup.find('div', 'sometext').find('span','title')['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're familiar with XPath and you don't need feature that specific to `BeautifulSoup`, then using `lxml` only is enough (or maybe even better since `lxml` is known to be faster) :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('the url')
root = html.fromstring(page.text)
r = root.xpath('//span[@class="title"]/text()')
print r
```